# get a derivative by knowing two numeric vectors

Tags: r, derivative

I know two vectors x and y, how can I calculate derivatives of y with respect to x in R ?

```
x<-rnorm(1000)
y<-x^2+x
```

I want to caculate derivative of y with respect to x: dy/dx; suppose I don't know the underlying function between x and y. There can be a value in derivative scale corresponding to each x.

Comment: If you plot these points: `plot(x,y, type="l")` it doesn't look much like a continuous function where a derivative makes sense. Is this really what you are doing?

Comment: You could calculate `dy/dx` if you had `y<-rnorm(1000)` and `x <- 1:1000`, but in your case you are not even guarenteed to have a function. You could have two x values with different y's, which a function can never have.

Comment: And in your second case the `dy/dx <- 2*x + 1`

Comment: @MikeWise, but this is only an example, in my question at hand, I don't know the underlying function linking x and y, but only two numeric vectors.

Comment: Well, you can find a function that is the "best-fit", using any one of a number of methods, and then you can just estimate the derivative by taking a numerical derivative of that best-fit function.

Comment: If you have a numerical estimate of a function, you can always take the derivative just by differencing.

Comment: You also need to make an assumption of what the functional form is. Like from the space of linear functions, polynomials, or what. Otherwise your "best-fit" problem won't have a solution.

Comment: @MikeWise OK，many thanks for your help

Comment: It is actually a better question for the `cross validated` stack exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the derivative use the numeric approximation: (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) or dy/dx.  In R use the diff function to calculate the difference between 2 consecutive points:

```
x<-rnorm(100)
y<-x^2+x

#find the average x between 2 points
avex<-x[-1]-diff(x)/2
#find the numerical approximation
#delta-y/delta-x
dydx<-diff(y)/diff(x)

#plot numeric approxiamtion
plot(x=avex, dydx)
#plot analytical answer
lines(x=avex, y=2*avex+1)
```

Answer (score 4):

The only problem with your data is that it is not sorted.

```
set.seed(2017)
x<-rnorm(1000)
y<-x^2+x

y  = y[order(x)]
x = sort(x)
plot(x,y)
```

[image: Original function]

Now you can take the y differences over the x differences.

```
plot(x[-1],diff(y)/diff(x))
abline(1,2)
```

[image: Derivative]

The result agrees well with the theoretical result d(x) = 2x+1

If you want to get you hands on the *function* for the derivative,  just use `approxfun` on all of the points that you have.

```
deriv = approxfun(x[-1], diff(y)/diff(x))
```

Once again,  plotting this agrees well with the expected derivative.